# How to automatically link the users table to another table once a user gets registered in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create an e-commerce website, in which I have used the functionality of the Django authentication to allow users to register and login. However, in the registration form, I take the information from 2 tables at once, like this...
[image: Two tables are, User and Shipping]

In my models.py...

```
class Profile (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobileNumber = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Shipping, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=False)
    guest = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Shipping(models.Model):
    addressLine1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    addressLine2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    postalCode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    landmark = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=80)
```

And my forms.py...

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile
from store.models import Shipping


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    mobile_number  = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'mobile_number',  'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class AddressRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Shipping
        fields = ['addressLine1', 'addressLine2', 'city', 'postalCode', 'landmark']
```

My signals.py...

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

My views.py...

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from .forms import AddressRegisterForm
from .models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from . import signals
import django.dispatch
# Create your views here.



def register(request):
    if not request.user.username :
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
            form1 = AddressRegisterForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid():
                email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                if not User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                    messages.success(request, f"The Account created for {username}! You are now able to login.")
                    form1.save()
                    form.save()
                    return redirect('login')
                else:
                    messages.warning(request, f"The email is either invalid or already used to create an account")
        else:
            form1 = AddressRegisterForm()
            form = UserRegisterForm()
        return render (request, 'register.html', {"form":form, "form1":form1})
    else:
        username = request.user.username
        messages.warning(request, f"You are already logged in as {username}!")
        return redirect ('home')
```

And finally my template...

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="content-section mb-5">
    <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <div style="display: flex; width: 100%; justify-content: space-around;">
            <fieldset class="form-group mt-4" style="width: 48%;">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Register</legend>
                {{ form | crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="form-group mt-3" style="width: 48%;">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Shipping info</legend>
                {{ form1 | crispy }}
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign up</button>                
            <small class="text-muted ml-3"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></small>
        </div>
        
    </form>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">Already have an account? <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign in</a></small>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

My information gets stored in the relevant tables, however, there seems to be no effect on the Profile table and remains to be empty...

Is there any way I can fire off django to link the user and the address in the Profile table once the user is registered.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the signals in the `ready()` function of your [app configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.receiver):

> Where should this code live?
>
> Strictly speaking, signal handling and registration code can live anywhere you like, although it’s recommended to avoid the application’s root module and its models module to minimize side-effects of importing code.
>
> In practice, signal handlers are usually defined in a signals submodule of the application they relate to. Signal receivers are connected in the ready() method of your application configuration class. If you’re using the receiver() decorator, import the signals submodule inside ready().

`yourapp/apps.py`:

```py
class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "yourapp"
    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

That should be enough to get the signals registered at the correct time.

Regarding two issues:

1. Existing user models in your database won't get updated, only new ones. Either drop your db and create new users or add a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) if your database is live or you want to keep the current.
2. Models connected by signals must be created without having any data for them. So you either must have [nullable fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#null) or fields with [defaults](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#default).

### Two forms

So you've posted 2 forms as one form in the HTML, this works because your forms don't share field names (except primary key, which isn't posted). For future reference, you can use a [form prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) to deal with duplicate field names and even use the same form for different purposes (shipping and billing address for example).

### On signals

Signals are used when an event happens (user is saved, user logs in), that is part of 3rd party code (in this case Django). But when you're the one creating the event, they are not needed as you can just do whatever you want right at where you create the event.

### Logged in or not

The correct test is:
`if not request.user.is_authenticated:`

### On to the solution

When saving related models with one or more forms, you should first create the models that can be saved without the other model of the relationship existing. These are:

- The model a foreign key points to (Shipping).
- The model of a OneToOneField, where the OneToOneField is **not** defined (User)

Due to the signal, our profile model will be created with empty values, but the form does not know that the `mobile_number` belongs on the Profile model, because it is a `Model`Form bound to the User `Model`. It treats `mobile_number` as a field that you will handle yourself. So let's do that:

```py
user = form.save()  # save returns the model instance created
profile = user.profile
profile.mobile_number = form.cleaned_data['mobile_number']
```

As said, we can create the address without problems and then we can link it to the profile:

```py
address = form1.save()  # save returns the model instance created
profile.address = address
```

And now we can save the profile:

```py
profile.save()
```

So putting it all together:

```py
def register(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:  # The correct way to test for logged in user
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
            form1 = AddressRegisterForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid():
                email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
                if not User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
                    messages.success(
                        request,
                        f"The Account created for {username}! You are now able to login.",
                    )
                    user = form.save()
                    profile = user.profile
                    profile.mobile_number = form.cleaned_data['mobile_number']
                    
                    address = form1.save()
                    profile.address = address
                    profile.save()

                    return redirect("login")
                else:
                    messages.warning(
                        request,
                        f"The email is either invalid or already used to create an account",
                    )
        else:
            form1 = AddressRegisterForm()
            form = UserRegisterForm()

        return render(request, "register.html", {"form": form, "form1": form1})
    else:
        username = request.user.username
        messages.warning(request, f"You are already logged in as {username}!")
        return redirect("home")
```

Comment: Yessss it definitely did work however, now I am faced with an error which I cant exactly figure out, "NOT NULL constraint failed: user_profile.address_id", is the error I'm facing....any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: And also now when I try to access the admin page I get an error saying... `Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
Exception Value: 
User has no profile.`

Comment: And also for some reason my `{% csrf_token %}` doesn't seem to be working, as all forms provide me with the error `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted`. I can guarantee that this error has come only after I added your code

Comment: well now that problem is solved but then as you said I made the 'mobileNumber' field in the Profile table null, and whenever a new user is created it always ignores that field. Any ideas on how the mobile number should also be automatically added. Thanks!

Comment: The csrf token is a separate issue, most likely, but in order to solve your address problem, empty mobile and possibly csrf, please add your view code and the part of the template from `<form>` to `</form>`.

Comment: The csrf token issure is sorted but the fact that in the Profile table the 'mobilrNumber' field is always ignored

Comment: Yes it is, and the mistake is in your view and / or template, which I've asked you post them 3 times now.

Comment: OMG im soo sorry i didnt get what you were trying to say, I hope this would be fine now thanks!!

Comment: Well seems like there stil is another error, now it says `NOT NULL constraint failed: user_profile.address_id`... Any ideas on how to fix that??

Comment: Change `address = models.ForeignKey(Shipping, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=False)` to `address = models.ForeignKey(Shipping, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226165/discussion-between-najaaz-and-melvyn).

Answer (score -1):

You can add all the fields related to the shipping address in the "profile" model.
When you want to access that data, you can simply use querysets.
In the models

```
class Profile (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobileNumber = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Shipping, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=False)
    guest = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    addressLine1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    addressLine2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    postalCode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    landmark = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=80)
```

and when you want to access the data, you can simply use querysets